# how to add SD card image into email body in android application

Tags: android

i want to add image into email body.i don't use attachment in mail.

```
  String imagepath ;
 Imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "ImagesCmas/"+image_name;

 final Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Happy Christmas");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Find Greeting Attachment");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Uri.parse(imagepath));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));
```

how to send SD card image into email body without attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some links - if you have a problem using these, post your code and I'll try to help further.

Android write to sd card folder

http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/writing-to-sd-card-in-android.html

https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.

You can add it as an attachment, or set the mime type to html and embed an  tag to an external image somewhere like

```
<img src="http://imgur.com/myimage.png"></img>
```

The email body can only contain html or plain text

Comment: Is it possible to add local sd card image as html content ?